# One table with two one to one relations SQL

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, relationship, one-to-one

In my database, I have tables for accounts,managers and customers. Both customers and managers has accounts. Two one to one relationships exist here between Customer-Account and Manager-Account. I have the AccountID as a FK in both customer and manager tables. Problem is that now nothing is preventing an account from being tied to a manager and a customer at the same time. How should i design such relation or how am i supposed to implement this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Mark each account with an *account type*. This column can have exactly one value for a given account.

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
 account_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 account_type TINYINT NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY (account_id, account_type)
);
```

Then make each type of account constrain itself to one specific account type.

```
CREATE TABLE Managers (
 account_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 account_type TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 FOREIGN KEY (account_id, account_type) 
   REFERENCES Accounts(account_id, account_type)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers (
 account_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 account_type TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
 FOREIGN KEY (account_id, account_type) 
   REFERENCES Accounts(account_id, account_type)
);
```

That establishes the default, but it doesn't prevent wrong data, for example making a row in Managers with account_type 4. To establish that constraint, you can use a trigger, or a CHECK constraint, or a foreign key to a small table with just one value.

---

Re your comment:

The way this works is that first you insert a row in Account, and you choose an account_type:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (account_id, account_type) VALUES (123, 1);
```

Now this row can only be referenced by a row with account_type=1.

If you only insert rows into Managers with account_type=1, and never insert rows into Customers with that account_type, then the row in Accounts must be referenced only by a Manager.

```
-- First example: works fine
INSERT INTO Managers (account_id, account_type) VALUES (123, 1);

-- Second example: wrong account_type for the Customers table
INSERT INTO Customers (account_id, account_type) VALUES (123, 1);

-- Third example: foreign key error, because Account 123 does not have account_type=2
INSERT INTO Customers (account_id, account_type) VALUES (123, 2);
```

> customers and managers have their own primary keys

This doesn't matter. I used account_id as the primary key in my example, but that's optional. If you have a different primary key column, it still works. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Managers (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 account_id INT NOT NULL,
 account_type TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 FOREIGN KEY (account_id, account_type) 
   REFERENCES Accounts(account_id, account_type)
);
```

Comment: well thanks for your reply. but customers and managers have their own primary keys i dun think this would be suitable. will u explain further how would it prevent such thing problem

Comment: Shouldn't your `Customers` and `Managers` tables above actually be `Customer_Accounts` and `Manager_Accounts`?  Otherwise, how can customers and managers have multiple accounts?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, the OP described a one-to-one relationship, not a one-to-many relationship.